# Cannot call `this.state.quantities.flatMap` because property `flatMap` is missing in `Array`

Tags: flowtype

I'm using `Array.prototype.flatMap`, and it's working, but Flow is complaining:

````
Cannot call `this.state.quantities.flatMap` because property `flatMap` is missing in  `Array`.```

Huh??? How do I fix this?
````

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.flatMap` was added to Flow in [version `0.103.0`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.103.0). You'll need to update to that version or a newer one before you can typecheck `flatMap`.